# Op Amp clipping signal way below rail

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio

I am trying to amplify a 0.4Vpp audio signal to 1Vpp using
 [OPA344](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa344.pdf) however my output is clipping around 0.5 volts even though my supply is 3.3v

Op-amp is in inverting configuration:
[image]

blue trace is input, yellow is output.
[image]

[UPDATE]
Fixed - However I'm considering putting the voltage divider on the output so changing the gain won't change the bias

Updated the schematic, this puts me at 1Vpp with a 500mv bias:
[image]

[image]

Comment: On a different note, you need to bias the non-inverting input to Vcc/2 to cope with positive input signals.

Comment: As @Transistor said, why is V+ connected to GND?

Comment: @Shamtam V+ isnt connected to ground. Its connected to 3.3 V

Comment: @Matt: I think he means the positive input

Comment: Yep, my mistake! I meant the + input of the amp, not the positive rail. If I had a bit more time I'd actually put together an answer. Short answer to the OP: the lower half of your signal is clipping at the bottom end on the input (when it dips below GND), which is why you see it clipping at 0.5V.

Comment: You haven't shown the output load on your schematic.

Comment: You've updated your schematic and shown a scope photo but forgotten to say whether you consider it fixed or not now.

Comment: Transistor, I'll consider it fixed - though I'm considering putting the voltage divider on the output so changing the gain won't change the bias.

Answer (score 3):

As @Transistor says, you need to put a resistor divider on the positive input of the op amp to bias it to 1.65 volts, so your signal can swing positive and negative about this point.  The larger problem is that the negative input is a virtual ground, and by using 220 nf and 1K, your output time constant is 220 usec.  You have created a high pass filter around 4500 hz (nothing but high audio will get through). Perhaps you should also consider a non-inverting amplifier.

Comment: Updated post with new non-inverting schematic, getting the output I want - just need to add a filter.